# How to pass event's argument to a ReactiveCommand?

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I have a custom control, which raises an event with an argument. I can bind a command to the event, but within the command handler argument is always null.

Here is the command binding:

```
this.BindCommand(ViewModel,
    vm => vm.MyCommand,
    v => v.InstanceOfCustomControl,
    toEvent: nameof(MyCustomControl.CustomEvent))
.DisposeWith(d);
```

Here is the command definition and implementation:

```
MyCommand = ReactiveCommand
    .CreateFromTask<CustomEventArgs, Unit>(MyCommandImpl);

public ReactiveCommand<CustomEventArgs, Unit> MyCommand{ get; set; }
private Task<Unit> MyCommandImpl(CustomEventArgs args)
{
    if (args is null) throw new Exception("WTF?");
}
```

I know for 100% that when event leaves custom control, it's argument is not null (=contains a value). But it arrives to the reactive command as null. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here, the `CustomEvent` on `MyCustomControlwill` be used to trigger command execution instead of the default event.So the default param `CustomEventArgs`is unavailable . If you want to pass value ,use the `CommandParameter` on your control .

Comment: But how can I pass what is stored within CustomEventArgs as a command parameter?

Comment: Looks like there might be an overload to pass the parameter according to the docs [here](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/binding-commands) and [here](https://reactiveui.net/api/reactiveui/commandbinderimplementation/493adb1e): 
_BindCommand also provides overloads that allow you to specify a parameter with which to execute the command. The parameter can be provided as a function, an observable or an expression that resolves a property on the view model_.

Comment: These are bound to the view model, not to the event which executes the command. At least as I understand it.

Comment: You can create an observable for the event using Observable.FromEvent or also FromEventPattern. You can then do myObs.InvokeCommand. InvokeCommand should pass along the event arts. You may have to do a .Select to retrieve the event args only for the InvokeCommand.

Comment: @GlennWatson, thanks for the tip: I have been trying to use FromEvent<> - no luck, but FromEventPattern<>  did the trick. You can copy my answer - I will mark it as an answer. Otherwise it goes to the community.

Answer (score 0):

In this case `Observable.FromEventPattern<CustomEventArgs>` should be used instead of `BindCommand` method:

```
Observable.FromEventPattern<CustomEventArgs>(
        InstanceOfCustomControl, 
        nameof(MyCustomControl.CustomEvent))
    .Subscribe(async nxt =>
    {
        await ViewModel.MyCommand.Execute(nxt.EventArgs);
    })
    .DisposeWith(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel better of the hack way introduced in the doc.

```cs
MyControl.Events().ValueChanged
    .Select(arg => arg.NewValue)
    .InvokeCommand(this, x => x.ViewModel!.WindowWidthChanged)
    .DisposeWith(d);
```

But I still wonder what's the usage of BindCommand "withParameter".